# remove nested span class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several different sections on a side bar, on a js page:

```
$('#side_bar1,#side_bar2,#side_bar3,#side_bar4,#side_bar5').css({'background-color':'#d3d5a9'});
$('#side_bar1,#side_bar2,#side_bar3,#side_bar4,#side_bar5').find("p[class=certstatus]").html('<span class="requiredSection">Required </span><span class="updateDueSection">Update Due</span>');
```

On one of the sections, I need to remove the "Update Due" span and append other tags. But for some reason I can't get the tag to remove, (but I'm able to append):

```
if($('#content').data("isCertified")){
    $('#side_bar3').css({'background-color':'#758d56'});
    $('#side_bar3').find("p[class=certstatus]").find('span.updateDueSection').remove();
    if($('#side_bar3').find("p[class=certstatus]").find('span.requiredSection').length > 0)
        $('#side_bar3').find("p[class=certstatus]").append('<br/>'); 

    $('#side_bar3').find("p[class=certstatus]>.requiredSection").css({'color':'#D3D5A9'});      
    $('#side_bar3').find("p[class=certstatus]").append('<span class="certified">Certified on </span>');
    $('#side_bar3').find("p[class=certstatus]").append('<span class="certdate">' + $('#content').data("certDate") + '</span>');
}
```

The css looks like this in the developer tools:

```
<p class="certstatus">
    <span class="requiredSection" style="color: rgb(211, 213, 169);">Required </span>
    <span class="updateDueSection">Update Due</span>
    <br>
    <span class="certified">Certified</span>
</p>
```

And just to be complete in my description, my css:

```
.updateDueSection {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#73100b;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.requiredSection {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#73100b;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.certified {
  background-image: url(../img/tickCertified.png);
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #D3D5A9;
}

.certstatus {
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:9px;
  margin:6px 0 0 16px;
}
```

How can I get the nested "updateDueSection" span removed?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's this have to do with Java?

Comment: You should probably `console.log` whether your selector (up until the `remove`) actually selects an element or might be empty. Also, any specific reason why you do `p[class=certstatus]` instead of `p.certstatus`? You should also think about caching references, it would make your code that much easier to read (and slightly faster).

Comment: did you try `.find('span.updateDueSection')` without `span`? It's not necessary anyway

Comment: And like christian314159 said.. Why are you using two different syntaxes for these two `find`s: `.find("p[class=certstatus]").find('span.updateDueSection')`?

Comment: @christian314159 I inherited code with this in there, and I'm also new to this, so I'm not sure why this was used, but I do know that it doesn't work.